# I have a editText that acts as a Searchbar, How do I hide recyclerView items if user hasn't typed anything on the Searchbar

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I want the items to appear only when the user starts typing something on the EditText

Here's my **Adapter**:

```java
 @NonNull
    @Override
    public UserAdapter.ImageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.user_item, parent, false);
        return new UserAdapter.ImageViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final UserAdapter.ImageViewHolder holder, final int position) {
...
}
```

Here's the Search **Fragment**:

```
       userList = new ArrayList<>();
        userAdapter = new UserSearchMessageAdapter(getContext(), userList, true);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(userAdapter);

        readUsers();
        search_bar.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                searchUsers(charSequence.toString().toLowerCase());
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    private void searchUsers(String s){
        Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").orderByChild("username")
                .startAt(s)
                .endAt(s+"\uf8ff");

        query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                userList.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);
                    userList.add(user);
                }

                userAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void readUsers() {

        final FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");

        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (search_bar.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    userList.clear();
                    for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);

                        userList.add(user);

                    }

                    userAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** 
You can hide the recyclerview when the user hasnt typed anything in the edittext

```
    @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

          if(charSeqeunce.equals(""))recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
else {searchUsers(charSequence.toString().toLowerCase()); 
recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
            }
```

and you can just show an empty state image instead.
When the user types something in the edittext then you can show them the recyclerview back and hide the empty state image!
Hope this helps!

Comment: @Yuza I am sorry, you have to add "recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);"
i will edit my answer.

Comment: I did set it to GONE and still, the items appear